# Send message for every k seconds using Telegram-CLI (Lua)

Tags: linux, lua, telegram

I want to achieve some tasks by using [Telegram-CLI](https://github.com/vysheng/tg) (Lua), which able to:

- receive message and respond.
- **send message for every *k* seconds**

The first task I achieve it by edit the function named `on_msg_receive (msg)` in `test.lua` according to my own suit. However, I can't find any suitable function to achieve my second task.

In detail, I need something like this and this function will be fired for every *k* seconds and send out the message

```
function on_every_k_seconds ()
    send_msg (user_name, 'Hello World', ok_cb, false)
end
```

I know this function cannot work, because I have no idea how the function like `on_msg_receive (msg)` get fired. Can someone explain to me how the function `on_xxxxx ()` get fired as well?

Does anyone has any clues to achieve the second task? Thanks for replies.

Comment: what do you mean by sending a message in a fixed period? what's that period? describe what the function should do

Comment: @Piglet , :( sorry for my bad English. I edited the post. It is more clear now? The fixed period I mean is for every _k_ seconds (can be generalize to minutes, hours and so on). The function should be able to send message for every _k_ seconds.